# Possible to force unique SAEF-uploaded filenames?

Tags: assets, file-uploads, image

I'm currently building a site right now that allows registered members to add their own logo to entries they create via a SAEF. I have Assets installed for this site but also have SafeCracker File available.

I'm perceiving an issue where multiple members try uploading files like `logo.jpg` thus overwriting other member logos.

Is there a way to keep upload destinations (subfolders?) separate where a member only sees their uploads (if browsing current uploaded items ala Assets) or possibly randomization of uploaded filenames if using a standard File field?

I found [this answer on a different question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11702/randomize-filenames-of-uploaded-files) that mentioned that Assets prevents filename collisions but I'm not sure if it allows browsing of existing images, which is not something I want.

Thoughts? Ideas?

Comment: I found this in another SE question, but was unable to get it to do anything to the filename: https://github.com/rsanchez/safecracker_file_add_prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think Safecracker File automatically appends a number to the end of any duplicate filenames to avoid collisions. Have you verified that your perceived issue is actually an issue?

Comment: Wow, you *are* right. It does add a number on the end. I guess this could work as-is and I'd just have to deal with `logo232.jpg` after 231 other people upload the same filename.